# jquery: don't run script, if it contains .active

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, if-statement

I have a script that animates a menu. I don't want it to if the menu contains an object with an active class (.active). I can't figure it out. I have tried several things, but I guess I'm thinking all wrong. Can  you help me?

This is the script:

```
$('#navigation .toplevel, #navigation > ul > li').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).delay( idx * 600 ).fadeIn( 600 );
});
```

This is the markup:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="toplevel">Menu</a>
        <ul class="undermenu"> 
            <li><a href="#">1.0 Menuitem</a>             
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">1.1 Menuitem</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#">1.2 Menuitem</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2.0 Menuitem</a>             
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">2.1 Menuitem</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#">2.2 Menuitem</a></li>
                </ul> </li> 
        </ul> 
</div>
```

If an UL **does** contain an active-class, I want it to be shown per default and the LI (the parent) to get an .active-class.

Does it make any sense?

****EDIT:****

The script shall not run if the main UL contains a child (or a childs child) with .active-class. I guess it's a IF/THEN matter? But I don't know how to write it.

And...
If "UL LI UL LI **A**" is active the "UL **LI**" (parents, parents, parent :D) should be given .active class. How do I do this?

Thank you in advance... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to assign the `.active` class to parent UL elements. You can simply change the selector below to iterate over your UL elements and add the `.active` class to their parent LI elements:

```
$('#navigation > ul > li .active').each(function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
 });
```

This will ensure that none of your `.active` tags are animated:

```
$('#navigation .toplevel, #navigation > ul > li').not('.active').each(function(idx) { 
    $(this).delay( idx * 600 ).fadeIn( 600 ); 
});
```

Comment: What I ment, was that I don't want ANY animation, if the #navigation-div contains an .active.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with the :not() selector of jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

e.g. selecting li's not containing class active:
$('#navigation ul li:not(.active)').each...

---

Edit:

1. you can add an if clause like this:

```
if($('#navigation ul .active').size() != 0)
{
    $('#navigation .toplevel, #navigation > ul > li').each(function(idx)
    { 
       $(this).delay( idx * 600 ).fadeIn( 600 ); 
    });
}
```

2.

```
$('ul li').has('ul li a.active').addClass('active');
```

something like this should work.

check out: http://api.jquery.com/size/, http://api.jquery.com/addClass/, http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 0):

Add `:not(.active)` to your selector.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

```
$('#navigation .toplevel, #navigation > ul > li').each(function(idx) {
    $this = $(this);
    if( $this.find('li.active').length === 0 ) {
        $this.delay( idx * 600 ).fadeIn( 600 );
    }
});
```